# ServiceStack OrmLite and DateTimeOffset support in the UK

Tags: sql, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, datetimeoffset

I am getting an issue with **OrmLite** and **DateTimeOffset** support.  I am based in the UK and believe that it is related.

I have a table with a column of type **DateTimeOffset**.

I get the following SQL error when trying to insert into the **DateTimeOffset** column:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have run **SQL Profiler** and can see that the SQL being executed is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO "Table"
    ("InsertedDateTime")
VALUES
    ('23/04/2013 09:30:48 +00:00')
```

I am pretty sure that this is an issue with the **dd/mm/yy** vs **mm/dd/yy**.  If I convert the SQL to the following, it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO "Table"
    ("InsertedDateTime")
VALUES
    ('23-Apr-2013 09:30:48 +00:00')
```

**Have I got something configured incorrectly or is there something I need to do to get this to work correctly?**

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  Did you learn of a config setting anywhere?

Comment: No - I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the default date format. Try this one -

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

DECLARE @temp TABLE (col DATETIMEOFFSET)

INSERT INTO @temp (col)
SELECT '23-Apr-2013 09:30:48 +00:00'

INSERT INTO @temp (col)
SELECT '2013-04-23 09:30:48 +00:00'

INSERT INTO @temp (col)
SELECT '2013/04/23 09:30:48 +00:00'

INSERT INTO @temp (col)
SELECT '23/04/2013 09:30:48 +00:00'
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your comment. I am aware that your answer will solve it, but the question is in the context of the MicroORM ServiceStack.OrmLite.